# Keyboard shortcut to open Ubuntu file manager?

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, filemanager

Is there a keyboard shortcut to open the Ubuntu file manager?

If there isn't one by default, how can I set such a shortcut?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It is under System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Launchers, and by default on  my system it is set to `Explorer` key (whatever that means), but personally i've set it to Super + E , since this is the same as Window's shortcut, which is what I used to use a lot year and half ago when I still was a Windows user. Just click on the area where the description for key is, it will say `new accelerator` and press keys you want to set

[image]

And if you want to create a shortcut to open some directory other than home, go to Custom shortcuts, and set a new shortcut for `nautilus /path/to/dir` command. For instance, `nautilus /usr/share/applications`

Comment: The "explorer" media key is an additional key on multi-media keyboards usually depicted by an icon of a little house and therefore aka the "home" key!  **;-)  :D :D :D**

Comment: The explorer opened is not as root. Is there any way to make shortcut of opening the explorer as root?

Comment: I clicked the `+` sign to add the custom shortcut, and named it as `Explorer` and command as `sudo nautilus`, and gave it the shortcut `super+E`, but it isn't working.

Comment: @Siraj `sudo` is command-line only command. You need to use `gksu` instead or `pkexec` instead. That will show you a GUI popup for password when you need to run filemanager with admin privilleges.  Note that this approach is not recommended. Nautilus has extension `nautilus-admin` so I would recommend you use that instead

Answer (score 0):

Naming it as Explorer/explorer didn't work for me.

On Xubuntu (which used the thunar file manager):

Under Settings -> Keyboard -> Application Shortcuts
Click Add -> set Command: `thunar` -> set shortcut to whatever you'd like (coming from Windows, I used <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>)

Alternatively you can check which command opens the file manager in Terminal, and put it as the Command value while making/editing a keybinding from the Settings.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is not shortcut, you can however create a custom one using the following procedure:

open settings, then navigate to devices then keyboard, here, you will see a lot of shortcuts,now scroll to the bottom until you find the '+' sign, click it,under name, type the name of your shortcut e.g 'Open navigator', under command, type 'nautilus' and then click set shortcut, a pop up appears, now set the combination that you deem fit e.g Super + E and add it and you will be good to go.
I am using Ubuntu 18.04 but I hope that this solution will work for most versions of Ubuntu/Linux