# Change keyboard shortcut to open Ubuntu 16.04 file manager through command line?

Tags: command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys

The question is similar to this one:
[Keyboard shortcut to open Ubuntu file manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/692880/keyboard-shortcut-to-open-ubuntu-file-manager)

Except that I would like to know whether it is possible to do it through command line, instead of GUI.

The task is to set the shortcut of `/home/usr` to `super+E` on a newly installed Ubuntu.

The reason to to this is that it is a pain to configure many machines through GUI. As a last resort, it is always possible to simulate mouse and key board to automate. However, for the sack of question, assuming that is not an option.

Comment: Try a look to [tag:xbindkeys]

Comment: @pomsky That looks right. Somehow `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings` returns `"@as []"`

Comment: That just means you don't have any custom keyboard shortcut set yet.

Answer (score 0):

The code is similar to this: [How to set custom keyboard shortcuts from terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/597395/how-to-set-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-from-terminal)
Except that it fixes the bug when there is no custom keys. Maybe someone with priviledge can mix the answers, and delete this one.

Python part:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess
import sys

# defining keys & strings to be used
key = "org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings"
subkey1 = key.replace(" ", ".")[:-1]+":"
item_s = "/"+key.replace(" ", "/").replace(".", "/")+"/"
firstname = "custom"
# get the current list of custom shortcuts
get = lambda cmd: subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd]).decode("utf-8")
# No custom keys
if   get("gsettings get "+key) == "@as []\n":
    n = 0
    current = list()
    new = item_s+firstname+str(n)+"/"
# Found custom keys
else:
    current = eval(get("gsettings get "+key))
    # make sure the additional keybinding mention is no duplicate
    n = 1
    while True:
        new = item_s+firstname+str(n)+"/"
        if new in current:
            n = n+1
        else:
            break
# add the new keybinding to the list
current.append(new)
# create the shortcut, set the name, command and shortcut key
cmd0 = 'gsettings set '+key+' "'+str(current)+'"'
cmd1 = 'gsettings set '+subkey1+new+" name '"+sys.argv[1]+"'"
cmd2 = 'gsettings set '+subkey1+new+" command '"+sys.argv[2]+"'"
cmd3 = 'gsettings set '+subkey1+new+" binding '"+sys.argv[3]+"'"

for cmd in [cmd0, cmd1, cmd2, cmd3]:
    subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd])
```

Call the script above in command line:

```
python3 /path/to/script.py 'home folder' 'nautilus /home/user' '<Super>e'
```